# Creating an as3isolib grid on stage using a class called from the Document Class

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I'm really lost here.
 I already checked many answers to "how to add something on stage from code that isn't on document class" but I cannot find an easy answer.

Well, I have two classes:

documentclass, declared on the FLA:

```
package 
{
    import as3isolib.display.scene.IsoGrid;
    import as3isolib.display.IsoView;
    import as3isolib.display.primitive.IsoBox;
    import as3isolib.display.scene.IsoScene;
    import flash.display.Sprite;

    import com.sb.*;
    import com.sb.services.*;
    import as3isolib.geom.Pt;

    //[SWF(width='760', height='600', backgroundColor='#000000', frameRate='30')]
    public class iso extends Sprite
    {
        private var grid:IsoGrid;
        private var scene:IsoScene;
        private var view:IsoView;

        //Script de Execução do jogo, depois do preloader.
        public function iso()
        {
            trace("It's Alive!");

            var map = new Map();
            map.IsoStarter();

            trace("Ending Loader.");

        }

    }

}
```

and the class map, i'm calling:

```
package com.sb
{
    import as3isolib.display.scene.IsoGrid;
    import as3isolib.display.IsoView;
    import as3isolib.display.primitive.IsoBox;
    import as3isolib.display.scene.IsoScene;

    import flash.display.MovieClip;

    import com.sb.*;
    import com.sb.services.*;
    import as3isolib.geom.Pt;

    public class Map extends MovieClip
    {

        private var grid:IsoGrid;
        private var scene:IsoScene;
        private var view:IsoView;

        public function Map()
        {
            //Loading ISO 
        }

        public function MakeMap()
        {

        }
        public function EnableScrolling()
        {

        }

        public function IsoStarter()
        {
            //Load ISO + Iso Configuration
            var box:IsoBox = new IsoBox();
            box.moveTo(15, 15, 0);

            var grid = new IsoGrid();
            grid.setGridSize(400, 400, 5);
            grid.cellSize = 25;
            grid.showOrigin = false;

            var scene = new IsoScene();
            scene.addChild(box);
            scene.addChild(grid);
            scene.render();

            var view = new IsoView();
            view.setSize(760, 600);
            view.centerOnPt(new Pt(150,150,0));
            view.addScene(scene);
            super.addChild(view);

        }

    }

}
```

BTW: This one works perfectly (beeing document class), but is not organized enough for me:

```
package 
{
    import as3isolib.display.scene.IsoGrid;
    import as3isolib.display.IsoView;
    import as3isolib.display.primitive.IsoBox;
    import as3isolib.display.scene.IsoScene;
    import flash.display.Sprite;

    import com.sb.*;
    import com.sb.services.*;
    import as3isolib.geom.Pt;

    //[SWF(width='760', height='600', backgroundColor='#000000', frameRate='30')]
    public class iso extends Sprite
    {
        private var grid:IsoGrid;
        private var scene:IsoScene;
        private var view:IsoView;

        //Script de Execução do jogo, depois do preloader.
        public function iso()
        {
            trace("It's Alive!");

            IsoStarter();

            trace("Ending Loader.");

        }


        /* *
         * Iso não pode ser chamado de outra classe senão a Document Root
         * Se for encontrado um jeito para fazer isso, transferir essas 
         * funções para outro script, afim de manter a ordem.
         */

        public function IsoStarter()
        {
            //Load ISO + Iso Configuration
            var box:IsoBox = new IsoBox();
            box.moveTo(15, 15, 0);

            var grid = new IsoGrid();
            grid.setGridSize(400, 400, 5);
            grid.cellSize = 25;
            grid.showOrigin = false;

            var scene = new IsoScene();
            scene.addChild(box);
            scene.addChild(grid);
            scene.render();

            var view = new IsoView();
            view.setSize(760, 600);
            view.centerOnPt(new Pt(150,150,0));
            view.addScene(scene);
            super.addChild(view);

        }


    }

}
```

Thanks.

Comment: sorry for the formatting errors :c

Comment: No problem. Use 4 spaces to create a code block. There must be a blank line after normal text for that to work though. \` \` is for inline code. http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code

Comment: thanks, i appreciate your correction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Map class, `super.addChild(view);` is adding your view to movieclip.  Try either `parent.addChild(view)` or `stage.addChild(view)`.  If neither of those work, try passing a reference to your document class into Map:

Change your document class to pass a reference to itself to Map:

```
 public function iso()
        {
            trace("It's Alive!");

            var map = new Map(this);
            map.IsoStarter();

            trace("Ending Loader.");

        }
```

And change the constructor in your Map class:

```
public class Map extends MovieClip
    {

        private var grid:IsoGrid;
        private var scene:IsoScene;
        private var view:IsoView;
        private var parentRef:iso;  // <-----------

        public function Map(parentClass:iso) // <-----------
        {
            this.parentRef = parentClass;
            //Loading ISO 
        }

        public function MakeMap()
        {

        }
        public function EnableScrolling()
        {

        }

        public function IsoStarter()
        {
            //Load ISO + Iso Configuration
            var box:IsoBox = new IsoBox();
            box.moveTo(15, 15, 0);

            var grid = new IsoGrid();
            grid.setGridSize(400, 400, 5);
            grid.cellSize = 25;
            grid.showOrigin = false;

            var scene = new IsoScene();
            scene.addChild(box);
            scene.addChild(grid);
            scene.render();

            var view = new IsoView();
            view.setSize(760, 600);
            view.centerOnPt(new Pt(150,150,0));
            view.addScene(scene);
            parentRef.addChild(view);     // <-----------

        }

    }
```

Comment: As an aside, it is common convention in AS3 to capitalize class names (Iso, Map) and use camelCase for function names (isoStarter, enableScrolling).  You don't have to do this, but it makes it easier to share code with others without confusion.